# where Column1 = case @var = 0 then null

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the following CTE hierarchical query.

```
declare @Cat_Fkey int = 0;
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT tblCategories.ID as  RowID,  CatEName as RowName
    FROM tblCategories 
    WHERE Cat_Fkey  is null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.id, cast(cte.RowName +' '+ t.CatEName as varchar(100))
    FROM tblCategories t
    INNER JOIN CTE ON t.Cat_Fkey = CTE.RowID    
)
```

I want to have a case on the where clause. For example

```
WHERE Cat_Fkey = case
when @Cat_Fkey = 0 then null
else @Cat_Fkey
end
```

I know where is null is not the same as = null, the query above is just a representation.

I want the outcome to be when @cat_fkey = 0, then where cat_fkey is null.
and when @cat_fkey <>, then where cat_fkey @cat_fkey.

Comment: Don't use a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE`. Use `AND` and `OR` clauses. `CASE` expressions are not SARGable, meaning that any indexes can't be used to aid the data engine to filter the rows from the table(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use boolean logic:

```
where 
    (@cat_fkey = 0 and cat_fkey is null)
    or (cat_fkey = @cat_fkey)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `and`/`or` as suggested by Larnu

```
WHERE (@Cat_Fkey = 0 and Cat_Fkey is null) or (Cat_Fkey = @Cat_Fkey)
```

Comment: I assume, due to this logic, this means that the column `Cat_Fkey` can have the value `0`?